# bootstrap carousel not working in low resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, screen-resolution

My Carousel is not working in low screen-resolution. If you zoom in the carousel will stop working and also the button beneath it.

See: http://www.terbruggenantiek.nl/?page=details&id=32

I cant find a solution for this problem.

many thanks!

Comment: The slider worked fine for me when I shrunk my screen size down. Perhaps you can provide more details on what you are using to test that is creating the problem? (for example what browser are you using and what version?)

Comment: well sorry for being unclear, i used the newest versions Chrome and Firefox... when the resolution is 1024x768 or below the carousel controls do not work. They work on mobile devices but not on desktop. The data in the carousel if Fetched with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change line 247 from

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-8">
```

Otherwise that column will draw bigger than it is supposed to and cover up the Carousel.

Comment: aah thats it, sounds kinda logic. damned small mistakes haha xD
Thanks!